# Add two paragraphs at same level

Tags: python-docx

I am new to python. I want to add two different paragraphs at same level in a docx file using python-docx.

I tried using sections but I am not able to split the page into two halves.

How can we add two paragraphs at the same level ?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: What do you mean "at the same level"? Please be more explicit. Are you talking about heading levels? Or perhaps "side-by-side" like in columns?

Comment: side by side like columns